# FATAL: Unable to run checkout callout dimension;jenkins in linux env

Tags: linux, jenkins, serena

I am having issues with Jenkins while setting up the job in Linux machine. In windows machine it is working fine. here is the console output from the Linux and windows, thank you for your help in advance.
dimension project I am using is Test:Test and folder to monitor is 'TestApp'

```
---Linux machine console error---
 Started by user 
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /opt/jenkins/workspace/TestApp
Deleting project workspace... done
[DIMENSIONS] Running checkout on master...
[DIMENSIONS] Running build in '/opt/jenkins/workspace/TestApp'...
[DIMENSIONS] Checking out project "Test:Test"...
[DIMENSIONS] Checking out directory 'TestApp'...
FATAL: Unable to run checkout callout - Dimension command failed -
     (UPDATE /BRIEF /DIR="TestApp"/WORKSET="Test:Test" /USER_DIR="/opt/jenkins/workspace/TestApp" )     (Using Current Project
'Test:Test'.
Using '/opt/jenkins/workspace/TestApp/' as the Project work area.
COR0006326E Error: Project 'Test:Test' does not contain the specified directory 'TestApp'
Scanning repository: 0.00 sec
Getting Project: 0.00 sec
)Finished: FAILURE


-------- windows machine success----
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\order\.jenkins\workspace\TestApp
[DIMENSIONS] Running checkout on master...
[DIMENSIONS] Running build in 'C:\Users\order\.jenkins\workspace\TestApp'...
[DIMENSIONS] Removing 'file:/C:/Users/order/.jenkins/workspace/TestApp/'...
[DIMENSIONS] Checking out project "Test:Test"...
[DIMENSIONS] Checking out directory 'TestApp'...
[DIMENSIONS] (Note: Dimensions command output was - 
[DIMENSIONS] SUCCESS: Using Current Project 'Test:Test'.
[DIMENSIONS] Using 'C:\Users\order\.jenkins\workspace\TestApp\' as the   Project work area.
[DIMENSIONS] Scanning repository: 0.24 sec
[DIMENSIONS] Scanning local work area: 0.28 sec
[DIMENSIONS]       Updated 'C:\Users\order\.jenkins\workspace\TestApp\TestApp\.project' using  
Item 'Test:PROJECT--1329969986.A-DAT;1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I could able to get rid of this issue by removing entry against folder to monitor option. so it could checkout code from dimension. the Pre Step-->> Execute Shell was really helpful. but strangely, when I provided PWD (present working Directory) to check the directory available, it was showing TestApp.